# Cannot see 'Deploy' link under Environments link for System Admin profile

Tags: deployment

What could be the reason for not seeing 'Deploy' sublink under 'Environments' link? I am a sys admin and I checked that 'Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions' is turned on for the profile.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

[Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions Permission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_modify_metadata_perm.htm#!) allows users to

> update metadata (including Apex) through Metadata API even if they don’t also have the Modify All Data permission. Metadata API is used for deployments using change sets, the Ant Migration Tool, or the Salesforce CLI.

It is a more restricted level of permission than, for example, `Customize Application`. It comes only with `View Setup and Configuration`. It's not intended to provide access to that area of Salesforce Setup, but only to support API deployments.

There are two items in the Deploy subtree in Setup:

- Deployment Settings requires Modify All Data in addition to Customize Application.
- Deployment Status is available without additional permissions.

There is no content in the Deploy header itself.

Comment: Still not clear about the solution David, what permission is required to see 'Deploy'?

Comment: Deployment Staus

Comment: @ShaliniSF Deployment Status is visible to a standard user in my org with the Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions permission.

Comment: I am a system admin and that is what is intriguing. I have seen that link always before. something has changed. and i verified the Sys admin profile has 'Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions permission' on.

Comment: @ShaliniSF I thought you were saying that _some other profile_ in your org, which has Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions, could not see Deployment Status. Are you saying that _as a system administrator_, you cannot?

Comment: System Administrators shouldn't need that permission and it has nothing to do with visibility of Deployment Status. Your local profile may have been modified to remove other key permissions.

Comment: Yes. Me being a system admin cannot see :(

Comment: So, what happened was that there were 2 users with names looking exactly the same, one of which was a standard profile. I was thinking I am using a sys admin but i was logged in as a standard profile user and that is why. Thanks for your help anyway.